# ¿Como Guardar datos con procedimintos almacenados con tablas relacionadas?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Quiero Guardar datos de de la tabla medico en la tabla varios, solo tomando su id de  la tabla medicos,como podria hacer pra solucionarlo datos de la base de datos.

```
        public void Insertar(int IdMedico, string Fecha, string Muestra, string Examen, string 
        Resultado, string Sensibilidad, string Especifidad, string TomaMuestra, string Hora)
        {
            //PROCEDIMIENTO TABLA VARIOS
            comando.Connection = conexion.AbrirConexion();
            comando.CommandText = "InsertarVarios";
            comando.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdMedico", IdMedico);
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fecha", Fecha);
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Muestra", Muestra);
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Examen", Examen);
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Resultado", Resultado);
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sensiblidad", Sensibilidad);
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Especifidad", Especifidad);
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TomaMuestra", TomaMuestra);
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Hora", Hora);
            comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
            comando.Parameters.Clear();
            conexion.CerrarConexion();


 //PROCEDIMIENTO TABLA MEDICO
 public void InsertarMedico(string Medico, string Paciente, int Edad, string Reportado)
        {
            comando.Connection = conexion.AbrirConexion();
            comando.CommandText = "InsertarMedicos";
            comando.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Medico", Medico);
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Paciente", Paciente);
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Edad", Edad);
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Reportado", Reportado);

            comando.ExecuteNonQuery();

            comando.Parameters.Clear();
```

Los datos de medico me los guarda, ahora solo quiero tomar esos datos y que me tome en la tabla varios para guardarlos posteriormenete.
Podrian darme una idea, de como solucionarlo

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask]. Y más importante aún [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Si no está el código del storedProcedure `dbo.InsertarMedicos`, ni sabemos la definición de las tablas, es difícil, darte una ayuda.

Comment: No esta muy claro tu escenario. Si los datos se guardarán en un solo proceso hacerlo en un único SP, primero insertar médico y obtener el IDENT_CURRENT, luego insertar en varios.

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte, ya logre solucionarlo.